# Boostrat 3.0 datepicker change position from right to left

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using a datepicker from bootstrap and I cant handle changing the position from right to left.

here is the html:

```
<div class="col-sm-8 input-group date " id="dpYears" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy"  data-date-viewmode="years">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" readonly="" value="">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i></span>
</div>
```

[link](http://websoftit.ro/sts/inregistrare.html) to the website

I tried with

```
$("#dpYears").datepicker({
    place: bottom-left
});
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: you need to play with css. there is no option available to manage position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your datepicker version doesn't work properly. Try downloading this [datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/zipball/1.3.0) and just replace bootstrap-datepicker.js, then call it with:

```
$("#dpYears").datepicker({
    orientation: "top left"
});
```

Important: check if it works good for you - if any other funcionalities are ok with that version of datepicker

Comment: Thanks buddy.. Its works for me... Specially i got issue on responsiveness

Comment: this is relevant to v3 also, while "Bootstrap 3 Datepicker" is v4